# How to get name or type of Message in OMNeT++

Tags: omnet++

I need to write a handleMessage() method in OMNeT++ which can process different types of incoming messages.
Messages can be of the type "MeasurementBatteryPacket" or "MeasurementEVPacket".
Is there a msg->getKind() function that would return the type or something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use `getKind()` if one set kind for these messages.
The standard way of recognizing the type of message inside `handleMessage()` is to try casting the message to particular type. It may be done using the following piece of code:

```
MeasurementBatteryPacket* battPacket = dynamic_cast<MeasurementBatteryPacket*>(msg);
if (battPacket != nullptr) {
   // msg is an instance of MeasurementBatteryPacket 
   // ...
} else {
   MeasurementEVPacket* measPacket = dynamic_cast<MeasurementEVPacket*>(msg);
   if (measPacket != nullptr) {
     // msg is an instance of  MeasurementEVPacket
     // ...
    } else {
     // recognizing other types

    }
}
```